# Is there a max character/word limit for heading tags?

Tags: html, semantic-markup, html-heading

I understand that heading tags are for semantic purposes, and as long as you don't abuse their purpose, in theory, you shouldn't be penalized in the search engines... But how long is too long?

I've always felt like it was an unspoken rule that you shouldn't put an entire paragraph in a `h*` tag, even a `h4`-`h6`, but I've never really questioned if that's right or wrong. But what about a 15-20 word sentence? Where's the line? And if there isn't a definitive character/word limit, what limitations should I observe when picking a `h*` tag over something like `p.subtitle`?

I know I'm probably over-thinking this, but would love some feedback nonetheless.

Comment: If it helps, a permitted parent of a heading is a `<p>` tag (accepts Flow Content) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Flow_content. **Short gut answer**: I don't believe you're outright penalized unless there's tons of keyword stuffing going on that doesn't relate to the rest of your site's content or description. Sorry, couldn't find any hard-and-fast rules here from search engine algorithms.

Comment: "what limitations should I observe when picking a h* tag over something like p.subtitle" *Never* use a heading for a subtitle. A p.subtitle is appropriate - even more so if you put it and its respective heading in a header element.

Comment: Do you ask about what the HTML spec says, or if/when search engines "penalize" it? The latter would be off-topic here, but on-topic on [webmasters.se].

Comment: I appreciate the answers guys, definitely gave me the insight I was looking for.

@unor - I wanted to know from an HTML spec perspective; should I edit my question to make that more clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What the HTML spec says

The HTML specifications don’t define such a limit, neither for `h1`-`h6` nor for any other element.

The places where one would expect such a limit to be mentioned would be the element’s definition itself ([The `h1`, `h2`, `h3`, `h4`, `h5`, and `h6` elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/sections.html#the-h1-h2-h3-h4-h5-and-h6-elements)) or the element’s content model ([phrasing content](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/dom.html#phrasing-content)). Specifically the [definition of *Text*](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/dom.html#text) doesn’t mention any limit.

In its section about parsing, the HTML 5.1 spec [notes](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/syntax.html#tree-construction) (bold emphasis mine):

> The algorithm described below places no limit on the depth of the DOM tree generated, or on the length of tag names, attribute names, attribute values, **`Text` nodes**, etc. While implementors are encouraged to avoid arbitrary limits, it is recognized that [practical concerns](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/infrastructure.html#hardware-limitations) will likely force user agents to impose nesting depth constraints.

So user agents will typically have their own limits, but these would be *very* high.

#### In practice

I don’t think that it would make sense to discuss an informal limit. Headings should be as long as they have to be. Think about long titles of works like scientific papers or novels, e.g., [this book has more than 50 words in its title](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/15591.Noisy_outlaws_unfriendly_blobs_and_some_other_things_that_aren_t_as_scary_maybe_depending_on_how_you_feel_about_lost_lands_stray_cellphones_creatures_from_the_sky_parents_who_disappear_in_Peru_a_man_named_Lars_Farf_and_one_other_story_):

```
<h1 class="book-title">
    Noisy outlaws, unfriendly blobs, and some other things that 
    aren't as scary, maybe, depending on how you feel about lost 
    lands, stray cellphones, creatures from the sky, parents who 
    disappear in Peru, a man named Lars Farf, and one other story 
    we couldn't quite finish, so maybe you could help us out
</h1>
```

That said, it’s of course important not to misuse heading elements. If you have a [subheading, subtitle, alternative title or tagline](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/common-idioms-without-dedicated-elements.html#common-idioms-without-dedicated-elements), don’t use a heading element. The common way to mark these cases up is using the `header` element, one heading element, and one or more `p` elements, e.g.:

```
<header>
  <h1><!-- the actual heading --></h1>
  <p><!-- the subheading or similar --></p>
</header>
```